# Inherit environment between ssh sessions

Tags: networking

I find myself modifying my current environment variables whilst changing between nodes quite frequently. Given this situation, I have been looking for a way of inheriting my temporary bash environment between nodes but have not found a solution that fits my needs.

I know there is **~/.ssh/environment** and **ssh -o SendEnv=$MYVAR user@domain** options but they are not exactly what I am looking for. My goal is to take the whole of my current environment variables, somehow. The static environment between nodes should be similar, so I guess it would not break anything... Hope this is not a naive guess.

Does anybody know a smart workaround or any other way I might have not considered yet? Any help would be appreciated.

Also, let me know if I have not been clear enough with my explanation, this is my first ever post!

Cheers.

Comment: Have you considered using RDP?  Remote Desktop Protocol is how Windows Remote Desktop connects, and also is used by remmina in Linux.  It is enabled by loading the xrdp package on the server.  Alternately, have you considered VNC?  VNC allows more than one virtual console and might be good.  I guess I am just asking what else you have tried?

Comment: I am using strict ssh on a Linux localhost to jump through other Linux machines, so there are not interactive sessions at all, therefore, I guess RDP or VNC would not help me in my case.For the sake of clarity, I am loading environment modules and modifying bash environment variables for compiling and I would just like a way to import on the go my whole bash variables.

Comment: OK.  I hope you get a good answer.  Thanks for posting this.  It could be very interesting.